# Problem with statemanager in SL4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, visualstatemanager, togglebutton

I have a togglebotton

```
<ToggleButton Padding="1">
                                <TextBlock>
            <Underline>Week</Underline>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </ToggleButton>
```

and what I need to change is set underline to false, when togglebutton is unchecked, and set it to true, when control is ckecked.

and now I have  only

```
 <ToggleButton Padding="1">
 <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">

                                        <VisualState x:Name="IsChecked">

                                            <Storyboard Duration="0:0:0">
```

and I can't figure out what next .

I'm not stick with conception with textblock. Text in the ToggleButton should be underline and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use VisualStateManager you would have to redefine the template of the ToggleButton - take a look at the MSDN [ToggleButton Syles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468212.aspx). Instead of that you can use Blend's triggers. First add to your project System.Windows.Interactivity.dll and Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll provided by [Expression Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3062) and then use the following code:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" Padding="1">
 <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock">
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=toggleButton}" Value="True">
     <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="TextDecorations">
      <ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
       <TextDecorationCollection>Underline</TextDecorationCollection>
      </ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
     </ei:ChangePropertyAction>
    </ei:DataTrigger>
     <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=toggleButton}" Value="False">
      <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="TextDecorations"/>
     </ei:DataTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
  Week
 </TextBlock>
</ToggleButton>
```

The ei: and i: are the following:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```